# MongoDB - Get most used documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to know if it's possible to get the most requested documents in a particular collection on MongoDB.

I have read the documentation, but I can't find any solution. For more detailed information, I have an _id (with an index), and I would like to know what top 20 _id requested.

Thanks.

Comment: In Oracle, how would you get the most requested row? What would be your intent here? And what does "requested" mean to you, since I could be reading or writing or both. If you are looking for existing "database counters" then there is no such thing down to the level of detail of "a document". If you needed to track such a thing, then you would need to set it up with code. But you probably should be a lot clearer about what you actually think you need and why.

Comment: @NeilLunn My objective is offer to users the most visited articles, and my most visited articles, is the most requested documents in this collection. I don't want to add a counter, because sometimes I have about 100 req/sec in a particular article.

Comment: I'm not asking for a converation but instead asking for you to clarify your question with "specifics". What you are asking is a very broad subject and I am asking that you narrow this down to what you actually need to do.

Comment: Ok, I will try to add more information...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be done by an inbuilt feature of MongoDB.

So you might need to do it manually by maintaining counter against each record and then fetching data based on the counter.

This is just a hack, if there is any proper way to do it, please post a new answer. I am curious myself. :)